# Yii: model attribute's comments/hints

Tags: yii

I need to have comments/hints for some fields in my Form. My idea is to describe it in model, just like attributeLabels. How can I do it?

And then it would be ideal, if the Gii Model (and Crud) generator would take it directly  from mysql column's comment

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So I see two questions here:

1. Describe hints in the model and display on the form.
2. Get hints from mysql comment

**Displaying Hints from Model**

Here's a slightly modified version of the default `login.php` file generated by `Yiic`

```
<div class="form">
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'login-form',
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
    'clientOptions'=>array(
        'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
    ),
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'username'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'username'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'username'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'password'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?>
        <p class="hint">
            Hint: You may login with <kbd>demo</kbd>/<kbd>demo</kbd> or <kbd>admin</kbd>/<kbd>admin</kbd>.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="row rememberMe">
        <?php echo $form->checkBox($model,'rememberMe'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->label($model,'rememberMe'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'rememberMe'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Login'); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div><!-- form -->
```

Let's move that password hint into the model by adding a `attributeHints()` method and a `getHint()` method to the `LoginForm.php` model.

```
    /**
     * Declares attribute hints.
     */
    public function attributeHints()
    {
        return array(
                'password'=>'Hint: You may login with <kbd>demo</kbd>/<kbd>demo</kbd> or <kbd>admin</kbd>/<kbd>admin</kbd>.',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Return a hint
     */
    public function getHint( $attribute )
    {
        $hints = $this->attributeHints();

        return $hints[$attribute];
    }
```

As you can see, we;ve moved the hint text from the view into the model and added a way to access it.

Now, back in `login.php`, let's add the hint tag based on data from the model.

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'password'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::tag('p', array('class'=>'hint'), $model->getHint('password')); ?>
</div>
```

So now we've changed the hardcoded hint into a generated element populated with data from the model.

Now, moving on to the second question.

**Getting hints from mySQL comments**

Unforunately, I am not fammiliar enough with Gii to know how to automatically generate the hints from mySQL comments. However, getting the mySQL comment data into the model is fairly easy.

To do this we can use the following mySQL query

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `tbl_user`
```

So let's add the comment to the password field

```
ALTER TABLE  `tbl_user` 
CHANGE  `password`  `password` VARCHAR( 256 ) 
CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL 
COMMENT  'Hint: You may login with <kbd>demo</kbd>/<kbd>demo</kbd> or <kbd>admin</kbd>/<kbd>admin</kbd>.';
```

And let's add the code to fetch it into our `attributeHints()` method.

```
    /**
     * Declares attribute hints.
     */
    public function attributeHints()
    {
        $columns= Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `tbl_user`')->queryAll();

        $comments=array();
        foreach($columns as $column){
            if( isset( $column['Comment'] ) )
            {
                $comments[ $column['Field'] ] = $column['Comment'];
            }

        }

        //Add any hardcoded hints here
        $hints = array(
                'username'=>'Enter username above',
        );

        //Return merged array
        return array_merge( $comments, $hints );
    }
```

We now have two ways to set comments, through mySQL comments or through hard coded statements.

Let's update our `login.php` file quick to include hints of both types.

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'username'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'username'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'username'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::tag('p', array('class'=>'hint'), $model->getHint('username')); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'password'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::tag('p', array('class'=>'hint'), $model->getHint('password')); ?>
</div>
```

And that's it!

[image: Login page]

Now our login page will look like this, with a username hint from the model and a password hint from the mySQL comment.

Answer (score 2):

As of Yii-1.1.13, a new attribute, [`comment`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbColumnSchema#comment-detail), has been added to `CMysqlColumnSchema` which is defined in parent `CDbColumnSchema`:

> comment of this column. Default value is empty string which means that no comment has been set for the column. Null value means that RDBMS does not support column comments at all (SQLite) or comment retrieval for the active RDBMS is not yet supported by the framework.

So we can use it to access the comment. Somewhat like this:

```
$modelObject->tableSchema->columns['column_name']->comment

// or if you are doing this within your model use
$this->tableSchema->columns['column_name']->comment
```

---

Note that the [`tableSchema`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#tableSchema-detail) is already set when any `CActiveRecord` [model is constructed](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.13/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php#L77) or even if the [static model](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.13/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php#L387) is used, so there are no new queries executed when we access the property.

---

A sample implementation within your model:

```
class MyModel extends CActiveRecord {
    // hints array will store the hints
    public $hints=array();

    public function init() {
        parent::init();
        $this->hints=self::initHints($this);
    }

    public static function initHints($model) {
        $comments=array();
        foreach ($model->tableSchema->columns as $aColumn){
            if(!empty($aColumn->comment))
                $comments["$aColumn->name"]=$aColumn->comment; 
        }
        return $comments;
    }

    public static function model($className=__CLASS__) {
        $model=parent::model($className);
        $model->hints=self::initHints($model);
        return $model;
    }

}
```

Now you can access hints as:

```
$model = new MyModel;
$single_column_hint=$model->hints['column_name'];

$model = MyModel::model();
$single_column_hint=$model->hints['column_name'];
```

---

For doing this through gii templates, you just need to copy the above code to your custom *model code template*, [read the guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii#extending-gii) to see how this can be done.

I would recommend having the code in a custom base class, from which you can derive your active records.